# Opening a file in Python, losing punctuation

Tags: python

I'm importing multiple text files into Python and store each document in a pandas dataframe. When this is finished, parts of the punctuation are missing. Character `-  :` are missing. For instances dates in the original text are stated like `01-01-2017` but are in presented in Python as `01012017`
This is part of the code I'm using to read in multiple text files.

```
f = open(path,"r")
df = df.append({'text':f.read()} , ignore_index = True)
f.close
```

What do I need to change to read the text with the correct and original format.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of text that has characters missing?

Comment: `df = df.append(...)` ... `df` will be equal to `None`. You also need to call `f.close`.

Comment: It's a [`pandas.DataFrame.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) issue, not an issue with `f.read()`.

Comment: it is indeed in append function. What's another way to read-in multiple text files from different paths? Store the text as a list? Eventually I need to extract the date from this text.